# How to declaratively assign a user ID to all new Leads that will be created?

Tags: ownership, record-owner

I want to make it so that all newly created leads will have a particular user ID as the owner ID. Where would I get about making that change?

Comment: Would the creation process use Lead Assignment Rules? That is certainly the easiest way to auto assign a Lead. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_leadrules.htm&type=5
Otherwise, a workflow rule could run and assign Lead Owner as well (Both Options 100% declarative)

Comment: thank you @GlenDeMarcos